# MongoDB 4.0.6 setup in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics, mongodb

I'm trying to setup mongoDB 4.0.6 analytics in Sitecore 9.3 instead of Default SQL analytics.

Are there any detailed guides on setting up mongo db for sitecore 9.3 ? I can't seem to find any documentation at all.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your setup topology you can take a look at the `6.1 Configure MongoDB Provider for xConnect` section in the installation guide provided in the sitecore documentation for 9.2  https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/92/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_92_Initial_Release.aspx

It should be working as based on https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0633863 for example 4.0.5 is compatible with 9.2 and 9.3

These would be the following steps:

- Enable the `sc.Xdb.Collection.Data.MongoDb.xml.disabled` configuration file by removing .disabled extension.
- Disable `sc.Xdb.Collection.Data.Sql.xml` configuration file by adding the .disabled file extension.
- Update the collection connection string to point to the MongoDB instance. It will look like this `<add name="collection" connectionString="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/usms_collection" />` You must also update the collection connection string in the indexer job that exists under the following roles:

  ```
     XP Single (XP0): xConnect
     XP Scaled (XP1): xConnect Collection & xConnect Collection Search
  ```
- Rebuild the xDB search indexes in Solr